# Editing ASME conference template for one line conference title

Tags: packages, titles, templates

I am using ASME LaTeX template for International Conference on Ocean, Offshore and Arctic Engineering (OMAE). If you look at the previous year's paper, the title of conference appears in one line. 
[image: Example of preious papers]

But after using the [template](http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/) provided at ASME website, a word from title of the conference drops to second line. Its making it look ugly. [image: Image of my paper]

Where am I supposed to make changes? In the style file or in my main tex file? what are those changes?

Update : I tried to insert title using \mbox{\hss ...}, but it does not work as I would like it to. [image: After using \mbox{\hss...}]

I have a strong feeling, this is where its making it go wrong. Since I am not an expert in Latex and on tight schedule, I'm reluctant to fiddle wit it. [image: screen shot of asme2e.cls file]

Update 2: tried taking out *the proceedings* from .cls file and putting the entire line, **
Proceedings of ASME 2017 36th International Conference on Ocean, Offshore and Arctic Engineering** inside `\mbox{\hss ....}`. It keeps the entire line intact, but it skips the right margin. The effect is disaster. [image: with entire title in \mbox{\hss...}]

Comment: there's a more "latex-y"way to do this, but ... i'd just put the first line in an `\mbox{\hss ... }` to make it appear to (la)tex as if it's shorter than it is.  the baselines are bad too, but that may just be a side effect of an extra line.

Comment: well, the \mbox{\hss...} trick does not work.  All it did was to make the a line break after first few words.

Comment: whatever is in an `\mbox` should never break.  I meant to put the entire contents of the line in the box, not just part of it.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. But something in the.cls file is conflicting with it, I guess.

Comment: Unless there is an MWE and link to the exact template used, it is quite difficult to analyze the issue

Comment: the exact template can be found [here] (http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/)

Comment: @subham what is an MWE ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Now I realized what you meant by _put the entire contents of the line in the box_ . fortunately I understood my folly but, unfortunately the trick makes it override the margin. I've updated it in question.

Comment: the `\hss` has to go on the *left* side of the long text.  it will then make the text extend into the *left* margin without changing `\hsize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally I found what was restricting the space.

```
    def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null\vspace*{-26pt}             % Took out ASMElogo provision
   \vbox{\hbox to \textwidth{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hskip1pc}}
   \hbox to 46pt{\vbox to 46pt{\vss\hsize46pt\vss}}\end{tabular}\hss
  \vbox{\hsize39pc\scriptsize\sf\vskip\baselineskip%
  \bannerfnt \begin{flushright} % added flushright to properly wrap long conference names
  \hfill \@conffullname\par 
  \hfill \@confshortname\par
  \hfill \@confmonth\ \@confdate, \@confyear, \@confcity, \@confcountry
```

if you change the `\vbox {\hsize39...` in line 838 of asme2e.cls file to `\vbox {\hsize43...` or howmuch extra space you need (1pc is approx 4mm) you can get rid of the entire issue.

[image: final result]

Comment: There's a newer ASME template in CTAN that supports long headings up to full width, including the ability to control line breaking if desired [https://ctan.org/pkg/asmeconf](https://ctan.org/pkg/asmeconf)